# iOS - retain View Controller state after presenting modal on top of it

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, delegates, modal-dialog

So I have a view controller A, which presents view controller B modally.  A is set as the delegate to B when B is presented.  B has two buttons at the top: Done and Cancel.  Both call

```
dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

But Done also calls a delegate method that stores some information in an array in A.  Everything works great, except that when I go back into B with some stuff already stored into the array from a previous Done click, and then click Cancel this time instead, the array is initialized to its default empty state.

How do I dismiss B while maintaining the existing state of that array?  Thanks.

## EDIT

Sorry - realized it was almost impossible to visualize what I was describing, so here is the gist of the code:

```
class A: UIViewController, BProtocol {

    var array: [User] = []

    func viewDidLoad() {
     ...
    }

    func BProtocolFunction(newArray) {
        array = newArray
    }

    func prepareForSegue() {
        ...
        B.delegate = self
    }

}


class B: UIViewController {
    var delegate: BProtocol?

    // Works great, copies this new array to the array in A.  However,
    //   if you go BACK into this modal, and then click cancel, that
    //   array is reset
    func doneButtonClicked() {
        delegate.BProtocolFunction(newArray)
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(...)
    }

    // So if the user clicks cancel, the modal is dismissed
    //   but the array is reset to []
    func cancelButtonClicked() {
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(...)
    }
}
```

So to summarize: the user goes from A to B.  B is presented modally.  When in B, they do some stuff, then click Done and a delegate method is called that changes an array in A, and the modal is dismissed.  After that, if they go back into B, and then click Cancel - the array is reset to [].  I want it to retain the array from the first Done click.

Comment: Please show code where you initialize the array, and where you update it.

Answer (score 0):

There must be some error somewhere in your code.

Judging from your posted code, there is no way your array would be reset to zero since your cancelButtonClicked does not fire any delegate

My guesses are:

1. You misplaced the action  target of the cancelButton to the doneButtonClicked() function.
2. Somewhere in your A ViewController, you reset the array other than in the BProtocolFunction